# Grouping objects by date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I take a list of objects from server, and they have the date as a property.
Cycling items that I have received, I need to arrange them in a table, but divided by days (by sections).

I'm having a bit of trouble because I would be able to fix everything within the loop.

What I do is, using a NSDateFormatteris create an array with the number of sections. But logically I do not know how to create everything inside the loop.

```
NSMutableArray *singleSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        int i = 0;
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM d EEEE"];
            NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:object.createdAt]];
            NSArray *dateArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            BOOL sectionExist = [sectionsArray containsObject:[dateArray objectAtIndex:1]];

            if (sectionExist == 0) {
                [sectionsArray addObject:[dateArray objectAtIndex:1]];
                [singleSectionArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               object.createdAt,@"date",
                                               object.objectId,@"objectId",
                                               nil]];
            } else {
               //???
            }

        }

...

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I would have such a structure

```
//Section
NSArray *singleSectionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];
NSDictionary * singleSectionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: singleSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
[dataArray singleSectionDictionary];
//Section
NSArray *singleSectionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object 4", @"Object 5", nil];
NSDictionary * singleSectionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: singleSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
[dataArray singleSectionDictionary];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (PFObject *object in objects) {
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM d EEEE"];
    NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:object.createdAt];
    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = sections[dateString];
    if (!sectionArray) {
        sectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        sections[dateString] = sectionArray;
    }

    [sectionArray addObject:@{ @"date" : object.createdAt, @"objectId" : object.objectId }];
}
```

That gives you a dictionary where each key is the section title (the date string) and each value is an array of objects for that section.

The trick now is to create an array containing the date keys such that the array is ordered how you want them to appear in the table. You can't simply sort the date strings because they will appear alphabetically instead of chronologically.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but could you also tell me how to enter the data in the array? I just can not do it. Thank you very much